# Keep getting "undefined" on very basic code

Tags: javascript, undefined

I'm starting to code on Javascript and practicing on codewars, I got this problem where I have to find the amount of times the most recurring number is repeated and I do get the correct answer but I also get an "undefined" below the answer and I can't seem to find the reason why... It may be something really simple that I'm missing but I'm stuck here and would appreaciate some help with an explanation.

```
function mostFrequentItemCount(collection){
    let a, b, c = 0, d = 0; 
    collection.sort((a,b) => a - b)
   
    for (i=0; i<collection.length; i++){
        if (collection[i] == collection[i-1]){
            b = a = a + 1;
            if (b>(c && d)){c = i; d = b}
        } else {b = a; a = 1}
    } console.log(d)

} console.log(mostFrequentItemCount([3, -1, -1, -1, 2, 3, -1, 3, -1, 2, 4, 9, 3]))
```

And this is the answer we get:

5

undefined

Comment: you are not returning anything in function `mostFrequentItemCount`

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: I'm expecting to get just the 5 which is the amount of times -1 has been repeated without the undefined

Comment: to clarify, you're missing: `return d;` at the end of your function.  Though you might like to give your variables better names as it's unclear what `d` is meant to be.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting undefined in this line.

```
console.log(mostFrequentItemCount([3, -1, -1, -1, 2, 3, -1, 3, -1, 2, 4, 9, 3])).
```

Because mostFrequentItemCount function is not returning any value, hence console.log - prints undefined

Answer (score 0):

You are getting correct result which is `5` from the `console.log` which is placed inside the function and getting `undefined` from the `console.log` where you are calling the function. When the function is getting called  and it didn't return any values, it will show as undefined.

You have to return the value from the function so that it will show there also.

```js
function mostFrequentItemCount(collection){
    let a, b, c = 0, d = 0; 
    collection.sort((a,b) => a - b)
   
    for (i=0; i<collection.length; i++){
        if (collection[i] == collection[i-1]){
            b = a = a + 1;
            if (b>(c && d)){c = i; d = b}
        } else {b = a; a = 1}
    } console.log(d) // This is showing the expected output
    
    return d; //This will return the value to where the function called
} 

console.log(mostFrequentItemCount([3, -1, -1, -1, 2, 3, -1, 3, -1, 2, 4, 9, 3]))
```

Answer (score -1):

```
function mostFrequentItemCount(collection){
  
collection.sort((a,b) => a - b)
  let a, b, c , d = 0;    
    for (i=0; i<collection.length; i++){
        if (collection[i] == collection[i-1]){
            b = a = a + 1;
            if (b>(c && d)){c=i; d=b}
        } else {b=a; a=1}
    } console.log(d)

} console.log(mostFrequentItemCount([3, -1, -1, -1, 2, 3, -1, 3, -1, 2, 4, 9, 3]))
```

Answer (score -1):

I already got it right, thanks for everyone feedback, the issue was that I was not returning anything on the function, basically return d fixed it as some of you suggested!

I already updated the code to be accepted on codewars and also replaced d for c since there was not really an use for it.

```
function mostFrequentItemCount(collection){

if(collection.length == 0) return 0

else{ let a, b, c = 1; 
collection.sort((a,b) => a - b)

for (i=0; i<collection.length; i++){
    if (collection[i] == collection[i-1]){
        b = a = a + 1;
        if (b >= c){c = b}
    } else {b = a; a = 1}
} return c }}
```

Comment: Since this answers your question. Consider marking this as the answer.